WSO2 API Manager 4.2 Carbon Portal path-relative style sheet import (PRSSI) Vulnerabilities
So I'm currently studying WSO2 APIM 4.2 and I found some low vulnerability in carbon portal related to path-relative style sheet import (PRSSI) to the /carbon/admin/login.jsp
How do i fix this? Is there any impact to other function if i make changes about this? Any insight is welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Please open a Git issue in this repository Product APIM and report the vulnerability and the steps.
